# How does 'kill -STOP and kill -CONT' work?

Tags: linux, kill

I'm facing an issue.
We have a clean script using to clean old files, and sometimes we need stop it for and will start it again later. Like the below processes. We use `kill -STOP $pid` and `kill -CONT $pid` in check.sh to control the clean.sh, `$pid` is all the pids of clean.sh (at there, they are 23939, 25804):

```
root      4321  0.0  0.0  74876  1184 ?        Ss    2015   0:25 crond
root     23547  0.0  0.0 102084  1604 ?        S     2015   0:00  \_ crond
root     23571  0.0  0.0   8728   972 ?        Ss    2015   0:00      \_ /bin/bash -c bash /home/test/sbin/check.sh >>/home/test/log/check.log 2>&1
root     23577  0.0  0.0   8732  1092 ?        S     2015   0:00          \_ bash /home/test/sbin/check.sh
root     23939  0.0  0.0   8860  1192 ?        S     2015   0:45              \_ bash /home/test/bin/clean.sh 30
root     25804  0.0  0.0   8860   620 ?        S     2015   0:00                  \_ bash /home/test/bin/clean.sh 30
root     25805  0.0  0.0  14432   284 ?        T     2015   0:00                      \_ ls -d ./455bb4cba6142427156d2b959b8b0986/120x60/ ./455bb4cba6142427156d2b959b8b0986/80x
root     25808  0.0  0.0   3816   432 ?        S     2015   0:00                      \_ wc -l
```

Once the check.sh stopped clean.sh, hours later, check.sh started clean.sh, but there is a strange thing, after a stop and continue, there is a child process '`ls -d ....`', it's still stopping.

Could you tell me if it's caused by wrong use of the signal? And how can I modify it?

Answer (score 2):

ok, same like my description is not clear, my bad English...
Not sure what's the reason, but there is a way to sovle it:
kill -CONT $pid
pkill -CONT -P $pid

This will continue the child process.